# What is the A/L/M switch for on a Top Power TOP-300XP power supply?

Tags: power-supply, power

I can't seem to find any information on what the switch is used for:
A is setting 1
L is setting 2
M is setting 3
[image: Picture of the Switch]

Comment: Googling TOP-300XP doesn't yield much results. Can you be more specific. What is this a power supply for? Maybe a picture or link to the product?

Comment: its for a Desktop Computer, and yea i know iv been trying google for hours looking for any trace of what the switch is

Comment: I don't have an answer to the question but I found the email address to their customer support so that's worth a try: info@topower.com

Comment: il have to give that a try i was beginning to think this was a no longer existing brand but i guess i was just spelling the name wrong

Answer (score 0):

apparently its just a fan speed switch if anyone else has the same question:
A - Automatic
L - Low Speed
M - Medium Speed